# Using ParseServer Backend JS Library in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, parse-platform, qml, back4app

I'm trying to use the Parse Browser Javascrip Library from here https://unpkg.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js within QML (Qt 5.14).

My QML File just looks like that:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import "parse.js" as Parse

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
    Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"; // This is your Server URL
    Parse.initialize("BCrUQVkk80pCdeImSXoKXL5ZCtyyEZwbN7mAb11f", /* This is your Application ID */ "4wPYRKbpTJeCdmFNaS31AiQZ8344aaYubk6Uo8VW");// This is your Javascript key
    }
}
```

Taken from https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs?javascript#initializing-parse-sdk

However QML Output gives me a typeError in the Library and says I cant write to a global Property:

```
qrc:/parse.js:13: TypeError: Type error
qrc:/main.qml:12: Error: Invalid write to global property "serverURL"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - I do not really feel like implementing all the calls by myself using XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

While QML is ES7-compliant, it does not have the same kind of Javascript runtime as web browsers do. For instance, there's no Window or Document classes/objects and there is no cross-origin security. For more information as to what is supported see:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html

Also, in relation to your error message, see how globally scoped javascript is handled here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html

and how Javascript imports work generally:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html

In this particular case, you want to reference it like this instead:

```
Parse.Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com";
```

However, that JS file is likely to have problems with the QML environment since it is probably looking primarily for a Node.js or browser-compatible kind of Javascript environment.

Your best bet is to use the uncompressed version here: https://unpkg.com/parse@2.13.0/dist/parse.js

And see if you can port it to QML by fixing code that has dependencies on browser or Node-only capabilities. I've done that a few times with some other packages and it usually takes a reasonable amount of effort to get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately I know too little about Node and other JS Frameworks that may be used within the parse.js file; so I doubt I'll be able to port it to QML.

Unfortunately the Application is supposed to be Cross Platform (Android + iOS and MacOS and Windows) so I doubt I'll get around this by using any of the APIs for each of the platforms. I might give the low level C API a try though.

Comment: @denish An alternative is to implement your own library using QNetworkAccessManager based on CURL requests (the REST API): https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs?shell#introduction

Comment: Note, you don't have to implement your own calls on raw XMLHttpRequest. Libraries like Superagent.js are pretty easy to port to the QML JS environment and make working with REST APIs a lot easier.